# Yii2 Rest API Batch update and filtering

Tags: yii2, performbatchupdates, yii-rest

1. I am looking to implement batch insert and update in my Yii2 Rest API.

   For single record updation, I am using the Rest API call as

   https://xxxxxx.com/api/web/v1/contacts/update/1 . It wil update the record with ID = 1

   But Now I want to update multiple records with a single API call.How to call the API for that?
2. For data filtering I am using

   https://xxxxxx.com/api/web/v1/contacts?filter[contact_name][like]=sa to filter contact name.
   If I want to filter the data by id like ID in [1,2,3],How can i do that?

   Please let me know the work around for these two challenges.

   Thank you

Comment: This is against REST principles. If you really want to do this you will have to come up with some custom endpoint.

Comment: What about data filtering with multiple values?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be something like `filter[id][in][]=1&filter[id][in][]=2&filter[id][in][]=3`. Don't ask more than one question at once at StackOverflow, it's harder to filter.